# Passing datetimeoffset to web api

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2

I'm facing an issue with datetime offset.
I need to pass datetimeoffset to my web api, but i'm unable to send it to my web api. 
This is my model property:

```
 public DateTimeOffset? PlannedStart { get; set; }
 public DateTimeOffset? PlannedTarget { get; set; }
```

Here i'm passing from typescript:

```
 let body: string = JSON.stringify(this.sprintReview);
 let url: string = environment.baseUrl + "api/SprintReview/SaveSprintReview";
                this.baseService.post(url, body).subscribe((data: any) => {
                    this.alertContent = "Saved Successfully.";
 }
```

- my datetimepicker gives this "Sat Apr 21 2018 06:00:00 GMT+0530
  (India Standard Time) {}"
- But the response header "2018-04-21T00:30:00.000Z"
- but my web api receiveing this "{4/21/2018 12:30:00 AM +00:00}"

I understand that it substracts 5:30 hrs as my timezone is 5:30+GMT

Kindly help me to pass the datetimeoffset to my web api. I need to save the date time with offset in the db.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that your browser is already setting the information you need in the HTTP headers, but at present I don't think that W3C has approved a standard header for this purpose so relying on that could be problematic.

The only reliable method at the moment would be for you to add the time zone of your local machine to the JSON that you are sending.

W3C has published a paper discussing the issue of dealing with time zones, available at https://www.w3.org/TR/timezone/. You should give it a read before you implement a solution.

Comment: An alternative - if you have control of the server side - is to always store your values in zulu and only convert to time zones when making things visible to the user. I have generally found this to be the more flexible solution as it allows records to be compared and searched based on time, which is very difficult if all the records may be in different time zones.

I put this as a comment instead of an answer, because it doesn't actually answer your question - it just suggests there may be a different way to examine your problem.